# cypher query condition doesn't work as expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have this cypher query, and i need help to improve the output please:

```
MATCH (first:Hit) WHERE first.page_key =~ '(?i)(.*bonus.*)'
and NOT(()-[:NEXT*]->first)

MATCH (last:Hit) WHERE last.page_key =~ '(?i).*shop.*' 
and NOT(()<-[:NEXT*]-last)

MATCH  path=first-[:NEXT*]->last

with filter(n in NODES(path) where n:Hit) as filtered
with extract(v in filtered|lower(v.page)) as ex

UNWIND ex AS pages
with  COLLECT( distinct pages) as pages1,ex

return pages1,count(pages1) as cnt,length(pages1) as len
order by cnt desc
```

these are (part of) the results, after csv export: (domain names and pages are scrambled)

```
"[""/bonus12"",""bonus2"",""/register1"",""/shop""]",1,10
"[""bonus5"",""/shop"",""/shop4""]",1,6
"[""bonus1"",""bonus2"",""/shop""]",1,4
"[""bonus2"",""/register1"",""/register5"",""/shop""]",1,4
"[""bonus2"",""/shop""]",4,17
```

**first thing** i don't understand why i have the values :/bonus12",bonus2 in the results list although i have this condition:

```
and NOT(()-[:NEXT*]->first)
```

and same for /shop,/shop4 although i have this condition:

```
and NOT(()<-[:NEXT*]-last)
```

**second question** is how i replace this filter:

```
and NOT(()<-[:NEXT*]-last)
```

with "last page in the path with a name like `bonus` , and there can be other pages after, with another name..."

also, because i know neo4j only for 2 weeks, if anyone has feedback for the code above, i'll be thankful

here is a data model: (except the Hit should have a "page" property)

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=8wnskw

Lior

Comment: Please provide your entire query. For example, the `RETURN` clause is missing. Also, please document your data model.

Comment: Neo4j works as long as you need it to work :)

Comment: You can remove the stars from your predicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would clean up your query like this:

```
MATCH (first:Hit) WHERE first.page_key =~ '(?i)(.*bonus.*)' and NOT(()-[:NEXT]->first)
MATCH (last:Hit) WHERE last.page_key =~ '(?i).*shop.*' and NOT(()<-[:NEXT]-last)
// this will be potentially a large list,
// consider allShortestPaths()
MATCH  path=(first)-[:NEXT*]->(last)
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) where n:Hit)
UNWIND extract(v in nodes(path) | lower(v.page)) as page
RETURN distinct page
```